# How to implement optional template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

How do I implement optional template parameters?

I'd like to have a class `MyStruct<T1,T2,T3>`, where it's allowed to use only the first or the first two params. Now, the functions that process `MyStruct<T1,T2,T3>` should also somehow deal correctly with the unused template params.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
struct MyStruct {
  T1 t1; T2 t2; T3 t3;
  MyStruct() {}
  MyStruct(T1 const& t1_, T2 const& t2_, T3 const& t3_)
    : t1(t1_), t2(t2_), t3(t3_) {}
};

template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
MyStruct<T1, T2, T3> myplus(MyStruct<T1, T2, T3> const& x,
                MyStruct<T1, T2, T3> const& y) {
  return MyStruct<T1, T2, T3>(x.t1 + y.t1, x.t2 + y.t2, x.t3 + y.t3);
}

int main() {
  typedef MyStruct<int, double, std::string> Struct;
  Struct x(2, 5.6, "bar");
  Struct y(6, 4.1, "foo");
  Struct result = myplus(x, y);
  // (8, 9.7, "barfoo")
  std::cout << result.t1 << "," << result.t2 << "," << result.t3;
}
```

Now I'd like to change the code so that the above `main()` function still works, but the following would also work:

```
typedef MyStruct<std::string, int> Struct;
// result: ("barfoo", 5)
Struct result = myplus(Struct("bar", 2), Struct("foo", 3));
```

Or this:

```
typedef MyStruct<int> Struct;
// result: (5)
Struct result = myplus(Struct(2), Struct(3));
```

I think `boost::tuple` uses a similar trick, where you may use `boost::tuple<A>`, `boost::tuple<A,B>`, `boost::tuple<A,B,C>`, but I'm not sure how they do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get you correctly you should be able to pass default parameters for your template:

```
template<class T1, class T2 = Default, class T3 = Default>
```

Where you can substitue any type for the `Default`.

Comment: I see, and the `plus()` function will work if I define an `operator+(Default const& Default const&)` that returns a simple `Default()`. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using variadic templates, in C++11 (harder and way more complicated option); or, you can use default template parameters, as Boost.Tuple:

```
// boost/tuple/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp

// -- null_type --------------------------------------------------------
struct null_type {};

//...

// - tuple forward declaration -----------------------------------------------
template <
  class T0 = null_type, class T1 = null_type, class T2 = null_type,
  class T3 = null_type, class T4 = null_type, class T5 = null_type,
  class T6 = null_type, class T7 = null_type, class T8 = null_type,
  class T9 = null_type>
class tuple;
```

Comment: Just a note, as the boost docs say `The current version supports tuples with 0-10 elements.`. So there's not a lot of magic going on here. Just a hard-coded upper limit using default values up to that limit.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a deliberate "unused" type:

```
namespace detail { struct unused { }; }

template <typename T1, typename T2 = detail::unused, typename T3 = detai::unused>
struct MyStruct
{
    typedef T1 type1;
    typedef T2 type2;
    typedef T3 type3;

    explicit MyStruct(type1 const & t1,
                      type2 const & t2 = type2(),
                      type3 const & t3 = type3())
    : x1(t1), x2(t2), x3(t3)
    {  }

private:
    type1 x1;
    type2 x2;
    type3 x3;
};
```

Comment: I don't think putting `Unused` in an anonymous namespace is a good idea -- if `MyStruct` is put into a header, different translation units will get different `Unused`s, causing different `MyStruct`s and violating the ODR.